# Find $P(3\le X\le5)$ if $X$ has a geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Currently, I have the equation of a geometric distribution:

$$P(X=k) =(1-p)^{k-1}p$$

Additionally, I worked out that:
$$P(X \ge k) = (1-p)^{k-1}$$

From this, I'm trying to find $P(X\ge3\space\cap\space X\le5)$. Assuming that 'X' is an integer, this is also just the same as $P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)$. However, I want a more systematic way of going about this problem. I was thinking perhaps of something around the terms of $(1-P(X\ge5) + P(X\ge3)$, however, I'm sure my line of reasoning is lost on this one. What is a systematic way to go about this problem?

Comment: Please use `\le` and `\ge` instead of `<=` and `>=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is certainly correct, and I don't know that it's any more or less systematic than any other correct solution.

I guess maybe what you're worried about is that you needed to use the fact that $X$ was an integer in your reasoning and you want to be able to write down an expression for $P(X\ge 3 \cap X\le 5)$ for a general real-valued random variable.

Of course the simplicity any simplification of this expression depends on what you've already calculated. Let's say we're in your position and have calculated $ P(X\ge x)$ and $ P(X=x)$ for any $x$. One thing you can write is $$ P(X\ge 3 \cap X\le 5) = P(X\ge 3) - P(X>5).$$ This works by the same intuition that your solution works. You can further break down the second term to $$ P(X>5) = P(X\ge 5) - P(X=5)$$ and so write $$ P(X\ge 3 \cap X\le 5)  = P(X\ge 3) - P(X\ge 5) +P(X=5)$$ which is now only in terms of expressions of the form $P(X\ge x)$ or $P(X=x).$

Answer (score 1):

Try using the fact that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$, coupled with the fact that, in your case, $P(X \geq 5 \cup X\geq 3) = P(X \geq 3)$.

Is this a more systematic way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain by law of total probability that
$$
\Pr(X \geq 3 \land X \leq 5) = \Pr(X \geq 3) - \Pr(X \geq 3 \land X >5)
$$
and it is easy to see that
$$
\Pr(X \geq 3 \land X > 5) = \Pr(X \geq 6)
$$